# Vaadin: change CSS variables dynamically

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Is there a way to change dynamically the lumo primary colors:

```
html {
  --lumo-primary-text-color: hsl(214, 35%, 15%);
  --lumo-primary-color-50pct: rgba(140, 236, 0, 0.5);
  --lumo-primary-color-10pct: rgba(140, 236, 0, 0.1);
  --lumo-primary-color: #8CEC00;
  --lumo-primary-contrast-color: hsl(214, 35%, 15%);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,
Thomas

Comment: Hi! This is likely useful to you: https://demo.vaadin.com/lumo-editor/

Comment: Hello! I used the theme editor to get my colors. But how can I change this live in the application?

Comment: @Thomas So you mean you want to change them programmatically at runtime? Like let the user change some color? If so, do you want to do it in Java?

Comment: Hello Tarek! Yes, I want to change to colors during runtime.

Answer (score 8):

The CSS variables can be updated dynamically from Java like so

```
UI.getCurrent().getElement().getStyle().set("--lumo-primary-text-color", "hsl(214, 35%, 15%)")
```

This will update the variable's value for the whole UI. If you want to change the variable only for a specific component (and its children), then you can call `getElement().getStyle().set()` on that component only.

Comment: Wow, so easy! Thank you :)